# How to get AppPath to Executable file's directory using C language on Windows (using MinGW gcc )

Tags: c, path, mingw, shellexecute, getmodulefilename

My executable file is in this place --> D:\Examples\C_Pro\newApp.exe
Also in that "C_Pro" folder contain several files ( file1.txt, file2.txt, file44.exe, newApp.c )

In my newApp.c file, I includes a ShellExecute Function to execute "file44.exe" file in same folder like this --> ShellExecute(NULL,"open","D:\Examples\C_Pro\file44.exe",NULL,NULL,1)

in this way all work properly..

I'm talking about AppPath like thing in VB

But the case is I want to run this newApp.exe on different pc's
So I want to replace ""D:\Examples\C_Pro\" this by whatever the path that contain "newApp.exe" file in another pc. (like C:\Software\ )

I get the path using GetModuleFileName Function but it contain newApp.exe part
I want only at to the Point that new directory
PathRemoveFileSpec function doesn't work.

and also the return path of GetModuleFileName like --> D:\Examples\C_Pro\newApp.exe
but when we put some path in to ShellEcxecute the require double shalse (space sequence) like this --> D:\Examples\C_Pro\

How can I get rid of this problem.

Actual code snippt is this...

```
int main()
{
    ShellExecute(NULL,"open","D:\\Softwares\\TypingMaster700.exe",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

But I want to do like this. (this is dummy one, here "some_Funtion" means dummy function for explanation purpose.

```
int main()
{
    char *dirPath = some_Function(a,x,d);
    char *fullPath;
    fullPath = strcat(dirPath,"\\TypingMaster700.exe");
    ShellExecute(NULL,"open",fullPath,NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting the absolute path to the directory where the executable is located is not standardly supported in the C standard because not all systems where the program runs support such a concept. Nevertheless in practice it is a desirable function to have. In short: good question.

Unfortunately it is not so simple and if your program is invoked using `execl` c.s. it may even be impossible. You will have to replay the shell in determining which application to run and start with `argv[0]` as paulsm4 also does. On Linux if the path starts with `/`, then `argv[0]` is the absolute path to the executable and you can find the directory by stripping of the executable name at the end. On Windows you will have to check for `\` and possibly a drive letter, I'm not sure. We will assume Linux in the remainder, just read `\` for every `/` to apply it to Windows.

If `argv[0]` is not an absolute path as above, you should check if the it contains any `/` at all, because if it does it must be relative to `getcwd` as was described also by paulsm4.

If `argv[0]` does not contain any `/`, then you will have to run through the `PATH` environment variable to find the first directory containing `argv[0]`.

If that all fails, your application has been invoked through `execl` or one of its friends and they were not honest about the location of the executable. You are out of luck.

Comment: Thank you Bryan for ur detailed explanation. I'm doin on Windows using MinGW32 gcc compiler.. I will be in big trouble. is I can't do this My App is not Completed. because it have to run defferent pcs

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works on Windows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char buff[255];
  getcwd (buff, sizeof (buff));
  printf ("path=%s\\%s\n", buff, argv[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply, But this is not what I want. Can't put paths like this type --> D:\Examples\C_Pro\ in to ShellExecute funtion.
it requires path in this manner --> "D:\\Examples\\C_Pro\\"

Comment: No.  You're confusing a compile-time string literal (a constant in your code, like "c:\\moose\\turd") with a runtime string.  It's the *compiler* that sees the "\" and tries to interpret it as a metacharacter.  The string you get from "getcwd()" or "GetModuleFileName()" at runtime can be used as-is with other functions.

Comment: Thanks paul, I'll try and let you know

Comment: Bryan Olivier also makes a good point: some platforms (like DOS/Windows) return just the program name in argv[0]; other platforms (like Linux) return the entire path.  This may or may not be important for you to keep in mind.

Comment: I do like thi --> ShellExecute(NULL,"explore", getcwd (buff, sizeof (buff)),NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);

but it gives error ??/

Comment: PAul ... iys works... thank yyou soo much.. but do me another little favor.. I want to append another file name to getcwd() out put.

I do like this --> ShellExecute(NULL,"explore", strcpy(getcwd (buff, sizeof (buff)),"\\file44.exe"),NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL); 

but bot working

Comment: Hey paul... I did it.. Thanks a lot for ur help. because of u it is hepl ti me coz I get to now about getcwd() from you.. thanks a lot

Comment: Keep in mind that `getcwd()` returns the current directory. In general that is not the same directory that the executable image is in.